# if |f| + |g| are bounded are f and g bounded individually?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

I've tried this... but is this legit?

**my sol:**

Assume $|f| + |g|$ are bounded, then we have that $|(|f|+|g|)(x)| \leq M \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$.

We have that $M \geq |(|f|+|g|)(x)| =||f(x)|+|g(x)||=|f(x)|+|g(x)| \geq |f(x)| \geq 0$

so $M \geq |f(x)|$. This same logic applies for $g(x)$. So there is a number $M$ that is always greater than $|f(x)|$ and $|g(x)| \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$. So $f$ and $g$ are bounded.

Is this a logical explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Why do you think it is not legit ?

Comment: How do we know that f(x) can reach M? Isn't that a huge assumption we are making? Like f(x)=5 g(x)=2 are both bounded... |(|f|+|g|)(x)| = 7, so M=7. But M>=|f(x)| isn't true as f never reaches 7...

Comment: Yes but you have no problem with $5\le 7$, why $f(x)\le 7$ should be different. You are not required to find the best bound, just one that works. The equality case is not mandatory. For instance if I take $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then I can say $|f(x)|\le 1\le 13788$ so $M=13788$ is also a bound for $f$. **bound** is not the same thing as **maximum**.

Comment: So 1 <= 100 is true as it satisfies  one of the two conditions (<) even though its equality isn't true.

Comment: Yes exactly, symbol $\le$ means "inferior or equal", if either one is verified, it is true.

Comment: You could also separate to $M_1$ and $M_2$ and that way it's clearer that $f$ and $g$ need not have the same bound $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The symbol $\le$ means that the LHS is less than or equal to the RHS. It does **not** imply that equality is possible. In fact in this case the possibility of equality in $|f(x)| \le M$ is not the normal case. We have that $|f(x)|\le M-|g(x)|$ and for $|f(x)|$ to equal $M$ we would definitely need $|g(x)|=0$ which ought to be considered a special situation.